# Move Azure Cosmos DB to other tenant

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to move a Cosmos DB to another tenant? Suggestions for built in exports/imports, API or tools are welcome. I cant find anything in the Azure UI.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. If it's about moving between subscriptions, then you'll need to do an export and import (and you can search for those tools provided by the Cosmos DB team, or use a 3rd-party tool). This is not something you're going to find in the portal.

Comment: I am asking for moving a Cosmos DB from one tenant to another tenant. I tried downloading the Document DB migration Tool, but the source is local files on disk and I cant find any thing in the tool to export to local files. I haven't found any documentation on how to use the tool.

Comment: I maybe figured it out, there is an option to go directly through the connectionstring, I will get back when tested. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you want to simply rename your Azure Cosmos DB instance name? The approach is correct to export data, recreate the instance as desired, and then import the data back.